# When does next() get called in my python class?

Tags: python, class, iterator

```
class corpus_reader:
  def __init__(self, corpus_file_path):
      self.corpus_file_path = corpus_file_path
      import os
      walker = os.walk(self.corpus_file_path)
      print(self.corpus_file_path)
      directory_list = list(next(walker))
      directory_list = directory_list[2]
      corpus_as_list = directory_list
      self.corpus_as_list = corpus_as_list
  def get_corpus_as_list(self):
     return self.corpus_as_list

path = input("Please enter the file path" )
myCR = corpus_reader(path) 
print(myCR.get_corpus_as_list())
```

When I run this code, IDLE gives me a `StopIteration` error. I know this happens when next() is called one too many times, but I can't see how it is called more than once. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a `StopIteration` for the first call to

```
next(os.walk(some_dir))
```

if `some_dir` doesn't exist, or isn't a directory

Comment: But I know that `some_path` exists. If I run that same code, with the same file path I put in when input() gets called, in the interpreter, the code works just fine.

Comment: @DanV, does the process have read permission to the directory?

Comment: I think? If I run os.access(path, os.R_OK) in the interpreter, that returns true, and I enter that same path when I run the code above